# "For each player who has incurred more than $150 worth of penalties in total, find the player number and the total amount of penalties."

Tags: sql

SQL beginner here. I'm trying to find the player number and total amount of penalties for each player that has over 150 dollars in penalties, I've made a query for it but its somehow returning instead the summed amounts for every player, is there something I am missing?

Database and Table:

```
CREATE DATABASE Tennis;
Use Tennis;

CREATE TABLE PENALTIES
      (PAYMENTNO    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       PLAYERNO     INTEGER NOT NULL,
       PAYMENT_DATE DATE NOT NULL
                    CHECK (PAYMENT_DATE >= DATE('1969-12-31')),
       AMOUNT       DECIMAL(7,2)  NOT NULL
                    CHECK (AMOUNT > 0),
       FOREIGN KEY (PLAYERNO) REFERENCES PLAYERS (PLAYERNO))

INSERT INTO PENALTIES VALUES (1,  6, '1980-12-08',100)
;
INSERT INTO PENALTIES VALUES (2, 44, '1981-05-05', 75)
;
INSERT INTO PENALTIES VALUES (3, 27, '1983-09-10',100)
;
INSERT INTO PENALTIES VALUES (4,104, '1984-12-08', 50)
;
INSERT INTO PENALTIES VALUES (5, 44, '1980-12-08', 25)
;
INSERT INTO PENALTIES VALUES (6,  8, '1980-12-08', 25)
;
INSERT INTO PENALTIES VALUES (7, 44, '1982-12-30', 30)
;
INSERT INTO PENALTIES VALUES (8, 27, '1984-11-12', 75)
;
```

My Query:

```
SELECT PLAYERNO, SUM(AMOUNT)FROM PENALTIES WHERE (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM PENALTIES) > 150.00  GROUP BY PLAYERNO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wen you need to filter the results of a query after an aggregation with `GROUP BY`you should use the `HAVING` clause: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

So the following request should bring you the expected results

```
SELECT PLAYERNO, SUM(AMOUNT) FROM PENALTIES GROUP BY PLAYERNO HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) > 150.00
```